# Component extends with super class needs help to test

Tags: angular, angular-test

Here is my base class:

```
export class DetailsComponent
extends AddClinicComponent
implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{}
```

in the spec of `DetailsComponent.spec` I am tryin to write a testing, which is in `AddClinicComponent` component.

here is the test:

```
fit('it should open popup  on click of button add clinic button ', async(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'openDialog');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const removeButton =
        fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.hfs-add-btn');
    expect(removeButton).toBeTruthy();
    let event = new MouseEvent('click');
    removeButton.dispatchEvent(event);
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(component.openDialog).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
}));
```

But getting an error as :

`Error: Directive AddClinicComponent has no selector, please add it!` how to resolve it?
what is the correct way to test the extended component?

my super class:

```
import { TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AddClinicDataService } from '../services/personnel-add-clinic-data.service';
import { HFSClinicTaleSchema } from './hfs-clinic-table.schema';
export abstract class AddClinicComponent {
    popTableSchema;
    clinicTaleSchema;
    @ViewChild('popupTemp', { static: true })
    popupTemp: TemplateRef<HTMLAllCollection>;
    public primaryName = '';
    public primaryAdminId = '';
    public dialog: MatDialog;

    constructor(protected aAddClinicDataService: AddClinicDataService) {
        this.clinicTaleSchema = HFSClinicTaleSchema;
    }

    clinicRowGenerator(rows) {
        return rows.map((p) => {
            return {
                ...p,
                address: Object.values(p.address).filter((v) => v != null),
                transform: true,
            };
        });
    }

    handleAddClinic() {
        this.popTableSchema = { ...HFSClinicTaleSchema, rows: [] };
        this.openDialog(this.popupTemp);
    }
    openDialog(templateRef: TemplateRef<HTMLAllCollection>) {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(templateRef);
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
            console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
        });
    }

    addClinics() {
        const { rows } = this.popTableSchema;
        const transform = [...rows]
            .filter((r) => r.checked)
            .map((item) => ({ ...item, checked: false }));
        if (!transform.length) return;
        this.rowTransformer(transform);
        this.dialog.closeAll();
    }

    searchClinics($event: Event): void {
        $event.preventDefault();
        const formDetails = this.postProfile();
        const countryCodes = formDetails.countries.map((v) => v.codeId);
        const searchParams = {
            primaryAdminId: this.primaryAdminId,
            primaryName: this.primaryName,
            countryCodes: countryCodes.join(','),
        };
        this.fetchClinicList(
            `name=${this.primaryName}&adminUserName=${
                this.primaryAdminId
            }&countryCds=${countryCodes.join(',')}`
        );
        this.primaryAdminId = '';
        this.primaryName = '';
    }
    fetchClinicList(searchParams) {
        this.aAddClinicDataService
            .getClinicsList(searchParams)
            .subscribe((data) => {
                const nwRows = data?.map((d) => {
                    return {
                        ...d,
                        address: Object.values(d.address).filter(
                            (v) => v !== null
                        ),
                    };
                });
                this.popTableSchema = { ...this.popTableSchema, rows: nwRows };
            });
    }
    protected abstract rowTransformer(value);
    abstract postProfile();
}
```

after having some try:
I got this error:

```
 Error: This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 0 of the parameter list is invalid.
        This can happen if the dependency type is a primitive like a string or if an ancestor of this class is missing an Angular decorator.

        Please check that 1) the type for the parameter at index 0 is correct and 2) the correct Angular decorators are defined for this class and its ancestors.
```

**constructor of details component:**

```
constructor(
        private personnelViewDataService: PersonnelViewDataService,
        private personnelTranslateService: PersonnelTranslateService,
        private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
        public dialog: MatDialog,
        protected aAddClinicDataService: AddClinicDataService
    ) {
        super();
    }
```

constructor of `AddClinicComponent`

```
 constructor(protected aAddClinicDataService: AddClinicDataService) {
        this.clinicTaleSchema = HFSClinicTaleSchema;
    }
```

Comment: The super class should not have a component decorator. It should be a simple class

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Yes, my super class doesn't have the component decorator. added the super class for reference

Comment: can you add the constructor code for DetailsComponent

Comment: @Mr.Stash - add both constructor function please check the question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency injection works only if the class has an Angular decorator.

> DI is wired into the Angular framework and allows classes with Angular decorators, such as Components, Directives, Pipes, and Injectables, to configure dependencies that they need.

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

This could be causing the error, try to inject the service in the component class and when calling super pass the service to the extended class

**constructor of details component:**

```js
constructor(
  private personnelViewDataService: PersonnelViewDataService,
  private personnelTranslateService: PersonnelTranslateService,
  private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
  public dialog: MatDialog,
  public aAddClinicDataService: AddClinicDataService
) {
  super(aAddClinicDataService);
}
```